# Angular2: Creating a model and using it across components

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have created a component for my donut chart and also added a model donut.chart.model.ts as below. Now in my main component I want to create a variable for chartmodel datatype and call the donut component by passing this chartmodel. what steps do I need to follow to be able to create that variable in my main component.  I tried importing it but it didn't work.

```
import {chartModel} from './donutchart/model/donut.chart.model';



export interface ChartModel {
    series: ChartSeriesModel;
    title?: string;
    subtitle?: string;
}

export interface ChartSeriesModel {
    name: string;
    data: ChartDataModel[];
}

export interface ChartDataModel {
    name: string;
    value: string;

    y: number;

}
```

Comment: Post what you tried, and explain, clearly, what you mean by "it didn't work".

Comment: It throws below error : ERROR in C:/Projects/Highcharts/Highcharts/src/app/app.component.ts (3,9): Modul
e '"C:/Projects/Highcharts/Highcharts/src/app/donutchart/model/donut.chart.model
"' has no exported member 'chartModel'.)
C:/Projects/Highcharts/Highcharts/src/app/app.component.ts (78,10): Cannot find
name 'ChartModel'.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would import it in your main component with something like `import {ChartModel} from './donut.chart.model';`  Then you would need to declare a variable with it:

```
myModel: ChartModel;
```

This declares an object that TypeScript will try to verify as a `ChartModel` type.  At this point `myModel` is still undefined.  You then need to populate a value with either the response of the http call or manually:

```
this.myModel = <ChartModel>{ title: 'someTitle', subTitle: 'mySubtitle', etc...}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried the same.. when I build my project it says donut.chart.model "has no exported member 'chartModel'.)". Am I missing something.

Comment: Are you trying to import a lowercase name when the exported member is uppercase?

Comment: I imported it in my main component and when I tried to use it, it says "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined". My main component is mymodel: ChartModel;
   ngOnInit(){

this.mymodel = <ChartModel>{ title: 'abc', subtitle: 'cde'};


  }

Comment: Sounds like the view is trying to use he property `title` of `mymodel` before it is defined.  At the top of the component initialize `mymodel` as `mymodel: CharModel = <ChartModel>{};`

Comment: Still getting the same error. Am I missing any reference.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a plunkr or something whereI can see the whole thing(or relevant parts)?

Comment: I did a quick test by checking {{mymodel.title}} and displays abc properly. But when I assign my model to a component <sei-donut-chart [configuration] = "mymodel"> <sei-donut-chart> it throws "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined".

Comment: The `sei-donut-chart` is trying to use title before it's been assigned.  You can try two things:  using `?` like `{{mymodel?.title}}` or using `*ngIf="mymodel"` so that it doesn't try to use the property before it exists.

Comment: I tried this <sei-donut-chart [configuration] = "mymodel" *ngIf="mymodel"> <sei-donut-chart>. But it didn't work. I tried assigning the values in constructor and also at ngOnInit, but both didn't work. Do we have to check the model before passing it to a component?export class AppComponent  {


  constructor() {

this.mymodel = <ChartModel>{title:'abc', subtitle:'cde'};
  

  }

  mymodel: ChartModel ;

}

Comment: Not ordinarily but something is happening somewhere.  It would be really helpful if you had this working in a plunkr or your full code was on github or some place I could take a look at it.